# awk command to get the process name

Tags: bash, tomcat, awk

I am trying to get the process name using awk command in shell script as below

Pseudo code

```
app=`ssh tomcat@server ps -ef | grep $procid | grep -v "grep" | awk -F ' ' '{print $NF}' | sed 's/ //' | sed 's/\.jar//'`
```

The sample log file is as below

```
tomcat    4818     1  1 Jun15 ?        02:46:09  /usr/local/integration-banana.jar --server.port=9023
tomcat   10283     1  0  2016 ?        1-20:19:20 /usr/local/integration-mango.jar
tomcat   10655     1  0  2016 ?        1-21:29:32 /usr/local/integration-grapes.jar
tomcat    4062     1  1 Mar16 ?        1-01:47:37 /usr/local/integration-kiwi.jar --server.port=9012
```

Desired output is

```
banana
mango
grapes
kiwi
```

But in this case I am getting

```
--server.port
mango
grapes
--server.port
```

My understanding is `NF` used in `awk` command prints the last column , but from this log file I need to use `NF` as well to get the process names with out having `--server.port` address.
Could you please help on this .

Comment: what is `$procid` ?  is it the processId? or ids? show the example value of it.

Comment: I don't see how you get that output from that input, where is the `/usr/local/integration-` part of each line going?

Comment: It is process id.Puting the rest of the code
ssh tomcat@server netstat -tulpn | grep java > /home/arun/stat.out
for javaproc in `cat /home/arun/stat.out`; do
         procid=`echo $javaproc| awk -F ' ' '{print $NF}'| awk -F '/' '{print $1}'`
        port=`echo $javaproc | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'| awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
         hasserverport=`ps -ef | grep $procid | grep -v "grep" | grep -c "server\.port"`
        if [ $hasserverport -gt 0 ];then
  app=`ssh tomcat@server ps -ef | grep $procid | grep -v "grep" | awk -F ' ' '{print $NF}' | sed 's/ //' | sed 's/\.jar//'`

Comment: @Arun Comments don't format very well, could you please, instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44783748/edit) your question to include the extra information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array=( $(ssh tomcat@server ps -ef | awk '{print $8}' )
array=( ${array[@]##*-} )
array=( ${array[@]%\.*} )
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i ~ /\// ) { split($i,arry,".");split(arry[1],arry1,"-");print arry1[2] }  } }'
```

The above awk solution should work for the output of ps. We check each record for file paths (pattern matching against /). We then split the string into an array called arry first using "." and then use this array to further split using "-". This gives us the section of the filename required.

Answer (score 0):

If you see some codes like `ps -ef|grep|grep|sed|sed|awk......` 90% it is on a wrong way to your goal.

You should read the man page of `ps`, and try to make `ps` to give you information you need, for example it has `-p pidlist` to list processes only for given pids. There are a lot of output format options.

For your particular problem, you are searching among java processes, ok, there is `jps` tool shipped with `jdk`. Give it a try on your server just by `jps<enter>`, see what you got. Do a `man jps`, and check out the options, it will be most simply way to get the java process I guess, if you want to chop the `.jar` off, you can pipe to a `sed`, obviously, you have known how to do it.

Again, don't do `whatever|grep|grep|sed|sed|awkgrep|sed...`